# TYPO3: plugin not showing up in backend

Tags: typo3

This is T3 v7.7.25 and I tried to build my first extension. The idea is to have a selectable content element in the backend whose html template file does nothing but a php echo.

My emconf:

```
<?php

$EM_CONF[$_EXTKEY] = [
        'title' => 'Robert PHP',
        'description' => 'An extension to use PHP.',
        'category' => 'plugin',
        'author' => 'John Doe',
        'author_company' => 'John Doe Inc.',
        'author_email' => 'john.doe@example.com',
        'state' => 'alpha',
        'clearCacheOnLoad' => true,
        'version' => '0.0.0',
        'constraints' => array(
            'depends' => array(
            'extbase' => '6.0',
            'fluid' => '6.0',
            'typo3' => '6.0',
            )
        )
];
```

My ext_tables:

```
<?php

    if(!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) die ('Access denied.');


    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
        $_EXTKEY,
        'Robert',
        'Beschreibung fuer Auswahl'
    );
```

My localconf:

```
<?php

    if(!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) die ('Access denied.');

    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
        $_EXTKEY,
        'Robert',
        array(
            'Php' => 'include'
        ),
        array()
    );
```

My controller:

```
<?php

    class Tx_RobertPhp_Controller_PhpController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
    {
        public function includeAction() {

        }
    }
```

My template:

```
<?php
echo "echo aus der ext";
?>
```

I cannot choose the plugin in the backend, so something must be wrong with registerPlugin. But since I see no error message I find it very hard to track down the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can't use PHP tags in the Fluid template. The action in the Extbase Controller is using a Fluid Template.

The Fluid template must be in the right location: `Resources/Private/Templates/[ControllerName]/[ActionName].html`. In your case it should be `Resources/Private/Templates/Php/Include.html`.

Please use namespaces, it was introduced with PHP 5.3.

Just look at other extensions, like e.g. the Blog Example.

Comment: yes Thomas, that's exactly where I've put my template (as taught in the tutorials). Besides the php+fluid problem: are you saying that the reason the plugin isn't showing up in the backend is because I don't use namespaces?

Comment: it works if I click on "general plugin". from there I can choose my plugin in the "plugin" tab. I was expecting my plugin to show up when I click on "add content element" and on "plugins". why is it hidden like this?

Comment: If you want your content element in the "new content" wizard, you need to add PageTS as mentioned here: https://usetypo3.com/custom-fsc-element.html#c13

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 Frontend plugin is registered in `ext_localconf.php` file. if you want to add Backend modules then you need to add registerPlugin in `ext_tables.php` otherwise this is not required.

Also your `ext_localconf.php` file plugin configuration like below.

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') || die('Access denied.');

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'MyVendor.extensionkey',
    'plugin_name',
    array(
        'Controller' => 'action',
    ),
    // non-cacheable actions
    array(
        'Controller' => '',
    )
);
```

Also you need to specify the fluid template path as per above answers. For more details about extbase extension here [Extbase Extension](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/b-ExtbaseReference/Index.html)

Comment: this doesn't help, I do have a template at the right location and I changed the localconf according to you. still I don't see any plugin to pick :/

Comment: after add your changes once install / un-install extension is required. did you do this?

Comment: Also please update your question with latest changes. so i can check this.

Comment: I found out why, see my comment underneath Thomas' answer!